# How to do bulk insert using Stored Procedure In Spring DAO?

Tags: oracle, spring, stored-procedures, dao

Stored Procedure is used to insert rows into Oracle Table. Using Spring DAO, in Data Access Layer. How to do batch insert using Stored Procedure call... Flexiable enough to change SP, if need...

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do that:

1. You can change your stored procedure to have array params, then inside your stored procedure you iterate over the arrays and execute the inserts
2. You batch it on the Java side, and send them all in once. There are 3 ways to do that

   - Spring : [BatchSQLUpdate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/BatchSqlUpdate.html)
   - Spring : [JDBCTemplate.batchUpdate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)
   - Java : [PreparedStatement.addBatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29)
     These are all to call an SQL statement in a batch, but you can call a stored procedure as well as an sql with the following syntax

:

```
 ?=call procedurename(?, ?, ?)
```